# IIS url rewrite regex pattern not working

Tags: regex, iis, umbraco

I am using IIS 8.0 and Umbraco 7. I am trying to make a url like this: testdomain.com/somecategory?page=2 look like testdomain.com/somecategory/page/2. I created a rewrite rule but it doesn't work I always get a HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.

```
<rule name="pageNationRule" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.+)/(page)/(\d+)(|/)$"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}?{R:2}={R:3}"/>
</rule>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You will have to setup these rules in **UrlRewrite.config** in /config folder in your umbraco websites root.
To add new rule:

```
<add name="produktidrewrite" 
    virtualUrl="^~/product/(.*).aspx" 
    rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" 
    destinationUrl="~/product.aspx?productid=$1" 
    ignoreCase="true" />
```

Or you can add a custom route in your code.
Create a new class which inherit from from **Umbraco.Core.ApplicationEventHandler**
Overwrite **ApplicationStarted** to add your rules. Like this:

```
protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    //Custom route
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    "SomeName",
    "Something/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "ControllerName",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want the use the built in rewrite in Umbraco because it scales poorly.

Answer (score 0):

The error was probably because you had an extra / in the opening match tag. D'oh.

However, to simplify the rule you should be able to use:

```
<rule name="pageNationRule" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.+)/page/(\d+)/?$" ignoreCase="true">
   <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}?page={R:2}"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work, I think that the cms may be intercepting the request.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case because these rules are processed _before_ the Umbraco pipeline. I've revised the rule since you probably don't need the conditions.

Comment: I added the (|/) because I am not using a trailing slash but it is possible for the user to enter a trailing slash and I want to handle both cases.